# Upper bound of function explanation .

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, upper-lower-bounds

In a paper about numerical SDE's the author writes that for a certain function $b(t,x)$ , we define
$$
b_n(t,x) = \frac{1}{1 + n^{-a} \left | b(t,x) \right | }b(t,x) 
$$

for $ x\in \mathbb{R}^d, t \in[0,T]$.

Then he writes that
$$
\left | b_n(t,x) \right | \leq min(n^a, \left | b(t,x) \right |).
$$
I know that this holds, but I can't see the intuition behind it. Every answer is welcome.Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about the role of such a cut-off modification, or why the author did not just use the second bound formula, in a signed version, like $b_n(t,x)=\max(-n^a,\min(n^a,b(t,x)))$?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann
No, I'm just asking how to prove that the bound holds. I know that it may be trivial, but I don't seem to be able to find it. I need it so I can prove a similar bound for the function $ g_n(t,x) = b_n(t,x) + f(x) $ , where $f$ is everywhere Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: So you are asking why for $A,B>0$ one has $\frac{AB}{A+B}\le\max(A,B)$? Can you use $AB=\max(A,B)\min(A,B)$? One could even make the claim sharper, since $A+B\ge2\min(A,B)$.

Comment: @Lutz Well I can see with what you provided why $ \frac{AB}{A+B} \leq max(A,B) $, but the bound I am interested is the $min(A,B)$. Nevertheless, I don't think this will be useful for the $g_n$ bound, since i now have to bound $abc(1/a +1/b + 1/c)$ . But thanks for the reply,  I'm terrible in finding upper bounds .

Comment: Ah yes, but then you only need to insert that $\max(A,B)\le A+B$ to get the upper bound with the minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set $A=n^a>0$ and $B=|b(t,x)|\ge 0$, and additionally apply
$$
AB = \min(A,B)·\max(A,B)\\
\max(A,B)\le A+B
$$
then the quantity in question can be written as and bounded as
$$
|b_n(t,x)|=\frac{AB}{A+B}\le\frac{\min(A,B)·(A+B)}{A+B}=\min(A,B),
$$
as was claimed.

Comment: Thank you very much!